# The difference between Android's String.includes() and String.startsWith()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have found a very strange scenario that I can't understant. Let's have a code (React Native 0.43) that does not work on Android 7 (both emulator and real device).

```
const name = 'Medvěd kamčatský';

const t1 = name.startsWith('M'); // -> false
const t2 = name.includes('M'); // -> true
```

If I will remove accents from name both of the variables are true. Both of them are true on iOS as well. Is there a right approach how to handle such issues (or am I doing something wrong) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with `startsWith` on Android. Worked fine in debug on simulator but in production on a real device it wasn't returning the expected output for me. You might be experiencing said issue: [#11370](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11370)